# How can I extend git to see the files other people are editing with git or github?

Tags: git, github

I'm working on an OS project with unmergable source files that is living on github.

As a rule, we want to avoid merging files, and discourage parallel development of the same source. So far the team has been co-located, and coordination has not been hard.

However, I am concerned that as the project grows in the number of contributors we may run into issues with coordination.

It would be nice to know a few different things:

When I pull from master, is there anyone out there with changes that are ahead of master?

When I commit ahead of master, does anyone have changes ahead of master?

I'm new to git, so I don't know if there is anything like this built in.

If not, maybe I could use git hooks to automatically run these checks on commits etc.

EDIT:

From the comments and responses, it appears the answer to my original question about whether I can see what other people are working on is "no."

So, I've rephrased the question to how can I extend git to do what I want.

Furthermore:

Yes, my source code is really unmergable (or at least ridiculously painful to merge).

Yes, I know that I'm not using a workflow Git was designed for. However, it's the system I'm using. It doesn't do everything I want, so I want to extend it to make my workflow easier.

Comment: this would be working against the distributed nature of git. Whether people have commits in their local repos ahead of master is irrelevant, if GitHub is your source of truth.

Comment: Generally "source code" is mergeable. Why is yours not? That seems like the better problem to solve long term.

Comment: My code is not textual, so it can't be merged. It is a problem particular to the language I'm using, which is not a common case. For various reasons, we are using this language and the downside of it not being mergable is worth it. I am trying to find ways to mitigate this downside.

Answer (score 1):

Git is completely self-contained locally, so there's no way of knowing what people are doing with your repository on their local machines. So no, there's nothing built-in that would answer your questions. You *could* tell people to push all work to their forks or "personal branches" every day, but that would probably ruin atomicity of commits and result in a lot of unhelpful commit messages.

Having said that, what is beautiful about git (or rather version control with branches) is that you don't have to *care* too much about who is ahead or behind master. Since you don't seem to like merging (I really hope you're okay with "merges" that are actually just fast-forwards, otherwise you can't create additional branches), [rebasing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) is your friend. Setting a rule to have everyone rebase development branches off of master will keep the commit history in a straight line.

Comment: If the source files he's talking about a truly unmergable then git won't really help him at all, I suspect that he just need to hunker down and make sure nobody modifies the same file across branches or parallel workflows.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could have a look to [git lfs](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs) that has a command (in v2) to lock some un-mergeable files (and surely a command to see locked file):

https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-lock.1.ronn